# Building PMD jar with maven

Tags: java, maven, pmd

I'm trying to build PMD (https://github.com/pmd/pmd), but when I attempt to build, there are no artifacts (JAR file, etc.) in the `target/` directory of the project.

I am using Maven.  I have tried `mvn clean install` and `mvn clean package` and both run without error - but nothing in the `target/` directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to build a project that extends PMD with your own rules, or build a rule, using PMD for checking + your own validation rules?  Can you provide a snippet of your PMD plugin configuration?

Comment: Hi, I'm just trying to use PMD for checking with my own validation rules too. As far as I know, I have no PMD plugin configuration, I haven't modified anything other than adding a java file. From the documentation it looks like I can just create a rule (A java one, not an XPath one), and drop it in the right place (http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/howtowritearule.html)

I figured I could then rebuild the PMD jar and include my own rule. I intend to use external rulesets which will reference my new rules.

My issue is that I can't create a jar file from this once i'm done adding a rule.

Comment: In the past, you had to add the maven pmd plugin to your project.

Comment: Should there not be something in the pom.xml that says how to build the jar? If I was to try to build a jar file from the source code on github, is there a way I can do that? (Putting aside any changes I may make before doing that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PMD is a multi-module build. The top-level project has an artifact packaging type of `pom` so it has no output (other than the `pom.xml` file).

If you look at [the PMD project continuous integration build results](https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/job/pmd/job/pmd/lastSuccessfulBuild/net.sourceforge.pmd$pmd-core/), you will see that the JARs are in the sub-modules of the project.

In addition, there appears to be an "project aggregate" that probably zips up all the jars into one release package. It appears you get this by building the [`pmd-dist` module](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-dist/pom.xml).